# IntelliJ AWS SAM UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, intellij-idea, aws-sam-cli

I'm totally new to AWS and to lambda functions. Currently, I try to start my first "Hello world" program, using IntelliJ and Java. I programmed a Lambda Function in Java using AWS. I want to start it locally with the SAM CLI Builder inside a Maven Container (because I don't have Docker).

After solving some other errors I get this one after hitting `start`:

```
SAM Build finished exceptionally: Command did not exist successfully, exit code: 1
```

Earlier I got a warning, that something is wrong with UTF8 so the code would be somehow platform-dependent, but I have 0 clue honestly.

**Java SDK Version**
15.0.2

**SAM Version**
1.18.1

**Apache Maven Version**
3.6.3

And here is a traceback of the full process:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli(prog_name="sam")
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 152, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 121, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 160, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 250, in do_cli
    artifacts = builder.build()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 160, in build
    return build_strategy.build()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\build_strategy.py", line 41, in build
    result.update(self._build_functions(self._build_graph))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\build_strategy.py", line 52, in _build_functions
    function_build_results.update(self.build_single_function_definition(build_definition))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\build_strategy.py", line 116, in build_single_function_definition
    result = self._build_function(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 437, in _build_function
    return build_method(config, code_dir, artifacts_dir, scratch_dir, manifest_path, runtime, options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 486, in _build_function_in_process
    builder.build(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\builder.py", line 125, in build
    return workflow.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflow.py", line 58, in wrapper
    valid_path = binary_checker.validator.validate(executable_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\java_maven\maven_validator.py", line 33, in validate
    jvm_mv = self._get_major_version(maven_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\java_maven\maven_validator.py", line 51, in _get_major_version
    vs = self._get_jvm_string(maven_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\java_maven\maven_validator.py", line 69, in _get_jvm_string
    l_dec = l.decode()
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 25: invalid start byte
SAM Build finished exceptionally: Command did not exist successfully, exit code: 1**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write Lambda functions using the *Java runtime API* and IntelliJ. You can build a JAR file and deploy the Lambda function by using the Lambda console. Once you deploy the Lambda function, you can test it from the Lambda console.

You can log messages to Cloud Watch logs. Using the Lambda java runtime API in the IntelliJ IDE, you will avoid these exceptions. You will code your logic and deploy the JAR file, and it works.

In addition, you can easily use additional AWS Java APIs to invoke AWS services from the Lambda function.

To see a step by step AWS dev article that creates a Lambda function using the Lambda runtime API, see:

[Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)

Comment: Is it possible to trigger your skill with the Amazon Alexa too? Because this is the main reason why I want to do this. The function shall be called and respond by and with Alexa (with the amazon developer console for Alexa)

Comment: You can use any AWS API from within a Lambda function. In the above link, you can see we can invoke DynamoDB and SNS using the given APIs from within a Lambda function. If you are interested in using Alexa API, look at https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/alexaforbusiness/AlexaForBusinessClient.html